# Django display value text in formset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, formset

I wanna display the text value of a foreign key on the templante, in a way that the user cannot change it.
Template:

```
{% for form in formset %}
    <div class="">
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

HTML render:

```
<select name="form-0-semestre_solicitacao" id="id_form-0-semestre_solicitacao">
  <option value="">---------</option>
  <option value="5">2020/1</option>
  <option value="4">2019/2</option>
  <option value="3" selected="">2019/1</option>
  <option value="2">2018/2</option
  <option value="1">2018/1</option>
</select>
```

I tried `{{ field.initial }} and {{ field.value }}` but it displays 3 and i would like it to display the text: 2019/1

Update:
The field in display refers to the Foreign Key in semestre_solicitacao
models.py

```
class Solicitacao(models.Model):
    """Solicitações, depende de User e curso"""
    #TODO trocar homologada de boolean para choice homologada e não homologada, e ajustar forms
    solicitante = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    disciplina = models.ForeignKey(Disciplina, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    justificativa = models.TextField(("Justificativa para o pedido"),
                                     help_text="O candidato pode explicar os motivos para solicitar a prova, por exemplo: experiência profissional, cursos não regulares, aproveitamentos indeferidos, entre outros.", blank=True, null=True)
    documentos = models.FileField(("Documentos comprobatorios de conhecimentos"),
                                  upload_to=None, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True,
                                  validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['.pdf'])])
    data_solicitacao = models.DateTimeField(
        ("Data da solicitação"), auto_now_add=True)
    cursou_anteriormente = models.BooleanField(
        ("Cursou anteriormente a disciplina solicitada"), blank=True, null=True)
    homologada = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    semestre_solicitacao = models.ForeignKey(Calendario, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Views.py

```
from extra_views import ModelFormSetView
class ItemFormSetView(ModelFormSetView):
    model = Solicitacao
    fields = ['semestre_solicitacao', 'solicitante', 'disciplina', 'cursou_anteriormente']
    template_name = 'manage_solicitacoes.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cc:solicitacoes')
    factory_kwargs = {'extra': 0}

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        return super(ItemFormSetView, self).get_queryset().filter(semestre_solicitacao__slug=slug)
```

I'm using django-extra-views.

Update 2:
[I'm getting the top part of the image, and i would like something similar to the one in the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f5EL.png)

Others Models:

```
  class Calendario(models.Model):
    """Calendario referente as datas do semestre"""
    ano = models.CharField(
        ("Ano"), max_length=4,
        help_text='Ano dos pedidos, ex: 2020')
    semestre = models.CharField(
        ("Semestre"), max_length=1,
        help_text='Semestre dos pedidos')
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Calendário em vigor', default=True)
    inicio_solicitacoes = models.DateField(
        "Inicío das Solicitações", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    fim_solicitacoes = models.DateField(
        "Fim das Solicitações", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    inicio_recursos = models.DateField(
        "Inicío dos Recursos", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    fim_recursos = models.DateField(
        "Fim dos Recursos", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['-ano', '-semestre']
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['ano', 'semestre'], name='unique_ano_semestre')
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.ano}/{self.semestre}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("calendario:calendario-detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse("calendario:calendario-delete", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Garante que exista apenas um is_active=True e define a slug"""    
        slug_str = f'{self.ano}-{self.semestre}'
        unique_slugify(self, slug_str)
        if self.is_active:
            with transaction.atomic():
                Calendario.objects.filter(
                    is_active=True).update(is_active=False)
                return super(Calendario, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return super(Calendario, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_fields(self):
        """ Permite usar for no template para exibir todos os atributos do objeto"""
        return [(field.verbose_name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in Calendario._meta.fields]


class Curso(models.Model):
    """Cursos existente e ativos com matriz"""
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    abreviacao = models.CharField(
        'Abreviação', max_length=3, help_text='Máximo 3 letras')
    matriz = models.CharField(
        max_length=4, help_text='Ano de aprovação de matriz do curso')
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Ativo', default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20)

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['-is_active', 'nome']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug_str = self.abreviacao + self.matriz
        unique_slugify(self, slug_str)
        self.abreviacao = self.abreviacao.upper()
        super(Curso, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.abreviacao}/{self.matriz}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("curso:curso-detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

class Disciplina(models.Model):
    """Modelo disciplina"""
    codigo = models.CharField(("Código"), max_length=12, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    nome = models.CharField(("Nome da disciplina"), max_length=50)
    curso = models.ManyToManyField('Curso')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.codigo} - {self.nome}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Url para o template com detalhes de uma disciplinas especifica"""
        return reverse("curso:disciplina-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.codigo})
```

Comment: I am assuming your select values are static(i.e not coming from DB), use [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) for displaying choices in formField or in modelField

Comment: They are a foreign key, i'm gonna update the question with the model

Comment: If foreign key is involved then I guess 1,2,3,4 are ID values. You can add some yearMonthvalue field and set its value to 20YY/MM while entering FK data and return that yearMonthvalue it in __str__ method. I guess this should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, those are the ID, didn't understand how i do that, i tried doing {{ field.initial.__str__ }} but i did'nt accept. 
I put a image to give a better ideia of what i wanna do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ form.instance.solicitante }} e {{ form.instance.solicitante.curso }}
```

Did what i wanted